# IOS,Phonegap, JQM scrollbar with form elements

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, scrollbar

I am developing an Application for iPad,

My app has one long form, I need help with scrollbar ... i cannot scroll down my form..I want scrollbar so user can scroll the form

I have tried iscrollview but no luck, its not supporting form elements in IOS

I am using phonegap 2.9 , jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery Mobile : 1.3.2

Thanks in advance